# [Java]Connecting to solr from apache spark

Tags: java, solr, apache-spark

I am trying to connect to solr from apache spark using java. I am able to find some solution where they are connecting to solr cloud from spark by passing the zookeeper config. I am running my solr on standalone mode and havent configured the zookeeper. How can I connect my spark program to solr. Help or pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: I am facing the same issue If you have fix for this can you please share.

Comment: Please see if answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41428058/how-to-connect-spark-streaming-to-standalone-solr-on-windows/41443998#4654822 helps.