# How to connect Spark Streaming to standalone Solr on windows?

Tags: apache-spark, solr, spark-streaming

I want to integrate Spark Streaming with Standalone Solr. I am using Spark 1.6.1 and Solr 5.2 standalone on windows with no Zookeeper configuration. I am able to find some solution where they are connecting to Solr from spark by passing the Zookeeper config.
How can I connect my spark program to standalone Solr?

Answer (score 0):

Please see if this example is helpful http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#design-patterns-for-using-foreachrdd

From example, you will need to write your own Connection class which wraps object of [HttpSolrClient](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/5_3_1/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/HttpSolrClient.html) or [ConcurrentUpdateSolrClient](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/5_3_1/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/ConcurrentUpdateSolrClient.html). You need to also write your own ConnectionPool class which will implement pool of your own Connection objects (or if its thread safe, just return same singleton object).